# What is the Best way to set Disaster recovery setup for percona Xtra DB Cluster?

Tags: mysql, percona, mysql-cluster, percona-server, percona-toolkit

We do have a Percona XtraDB Cluster(Master-Master-Master) setup in one country. Now we want to setup a disaster recovery setup in some other country. Please provide us the best possible ways to do that.

Is it possible to link between PXC(as Master)and  Mysql community version (as Slave)?
Or else can we just add one more node to PXC itself which serves as slave in that cluster??

Percona version:5.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the latest Percona XtraDB cluster version it is possible to make WAN segments so that there is more efficient communication between nodes. If you didn't do that, all nodes would try to replicate to all nodes, which is highly inefficient for Galera. With Galera 3/PXC 5.6, you can establish those so that only one node at a time will replicate to the other segments. This was specifically thought for geographical redundancy.

Before 5.6:

```
  ---------------
 /     /   \     \
A --- B --- D --- E   (A, B, C Local nodes; D,E Remote nodes; all talk to all)
 \   /     /     /
   C ------------
```

After 5.6 (Galera 3):

```
[ A --- B ] --- [ D --- E ]   (no redundant communication between segments)
[  \   /  ]
[    C    ]
```

In any case, think that the round-trip time will limit the minimum latency for each transaction, which means that using geographical replication will make the cluster much slower.

An alternative option that you can setup is combining Galera and standard replication, like this:

```
 A --- B ~~~ D --- E (--- : Galera replication; ~~~: MySQL replication )
  \   /
    C
```

**Standard MySQL replication is way more efficient**, as it does not wait for the "slaves" to confirm the changes (it does not use group communication). **The disadvantage is clear: being asynchronous it does not guarantee that absolutely all changes applied to the primary cluster has been transmitted to the slave node or nodes.** If the replications is well managed that should only mean less than 1 second of transactions, but this is certainly a no-go for banking applications or other applications where loss of information is impossible even if the whole datacenter fails. Whoever, that is something that most web applications and services can handle. On the negative aspect, standard replication has some disadvantages, specially if it is not well managed, like potential data drifts or extra latency due to it being single-threaded.

Comment: As I'm new to DBA, can you please guide me how to configure that specific **MySQL** **replication** (~~~~~)

Comment: @NarasimhaT.Juvvigunta Setting up replication is way easier than setting up Galera. Refer to the official documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-howto.html I recommend you to use xtrabackup for it, as it is already installed on your system. Here it is another specific tutorial regarding Galera + asynchronous replication: http://www.severalnines.com/blog/asynchronous-replication-galera-cluster-mysql-server-gtid Please ask another question for further clarification, but I recommend you to first read the multiple tutorials available.